# Is there an easy SELECT-Statement that creates an empty set?

Tags: mysql, select, set-theory

Is there an easy and simple way to create a result table that has specified columns but zero rows? In set theory this is called an empty set, but since relational databases use multidimensional sets the term doesn't fit perfectly. I have tried these two queries, but both deliver exactly one row and not zero rows:

- SELECT '' AS ID;
- SELECT null AS ID;

But what I want is the same result as this query:

- SELECT ID FROM sometable WHERE false;

I'm searching for a more elegant way because I don't want to have a table involved, so the query is independent from any database scheme. Also a generic query might be a bit faster (not that it would matter for such a query).

Comment: An 'empty set' will not really be a MySQL result. It will just say 'nothing returned', there are no table headers either. Try `select 0 limit 0`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT "ID" LIMIT 0;
```

Without any real tables.

Do note that most (My)SQL clients simply will display "Empty set". However, it actually does what you want:

```
create table test.test_table 
select "ID" limit 0;

show create table test.test_table\G

Table: test_table
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `ID` varchar(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL default ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think about the LIMIT-Keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NULL AS ID) AS x WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: As I explained, I asked if there is a way without involving a table. your query is exactly the same as the query I stated above, just replacing "false" with "1=0"

Comment: Thanks. Works too, but I like the LIMIT-Version more, since it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DUAL` pseudo-table.

```
SELECT whatever FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0
```

Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) (look for the DUAL section).